# How to pivot Weekend Dates as column dynamically in SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have a #temp table output, which I am trying to bring the weekend dates as columns.
When I run the query I get this error `"Parse error at line: 5, column: 34: Incorrect syntax near '2022'."`, Can someone please help with what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.
[#TABLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKMAQ.png)

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @col =
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(t.[WeekEnd], ',')
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT [WeekEnd] FROM #TABLE) AS t
);

SET @sql
    = 'Select *, ' + @col+ '
from
(select #TABLE.PTLITNBR,#TABLE.PTLWHSE,#TABLE.PTLDATATYPE,#TABLE.WeekEnd,#TABLE.Orders from #TABLE) as t
PIVOT
(MAX(Orders) for WeekEnd in (' + @col + N')) as Pivot_Table';

EXECUTE (@sql);
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to provide a sensible answer. Try explaining what you are doing in more detail, and then what your goal is. The best I can figure from this is that you want to use the content of the `WeekEnd` column to do... something, but it's not clear what.  It would also help to define which RDBMS you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols =
(
SELECT string_agg(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), QUOTENAME(TempTb.WeekEnd)), ', ')
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT WeekEnd FROM #temp1) TempTb --distinct weekend dates selected as there a
);

SET @query
= N'SELECT p.PTLWHSE, p.PTLITNBR,  p.PTLDATATYPE, ' + @cols
+ N' from
(
select PTLWHSE,PTLITNBR,PTLDATATYPE,WeekEnd, Orders
from #temp1 AS TempTb
) x
pivot
(
max(Orders)
for WeekEnd in (' + @cols + N')
) p ';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).